# FltReadFile funcation for reading more than 1 kb file

Tags: wdk, minifilter, windows-kernel

I am using FltReadFile function from WDK for reading files. I am able to read only 1kb file. How to read file having more than 1kb??
THank you.

```
offset.QuadPart = bytesRead = 0;
    status = FltReadFile( Instance,
                          FileObject,
                          &offset,
                          length,
                          buffer,
                          FLTFL_IO_OPERATION_NON_CACHED |
                          FLTFL_IO_OPERATION_DO_NOT_UPDATE_BYTE_OFFSET,
                          &bytesRead,
                          NULL,
                          NULL );
```

Comment: You need to show more code.  What are the values of length and offset?  What status is being returned when you try to read a larger file?

Comment: value of offset is 0
value of length is 1024
I have set flag FLTFL_IO_OPERATION_DO_NOT_UPDATE_BYTE_OFFSET but still offset is not updating when i try with loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the flag `FLTFL_IO_OPERATION_DO_NOT_UPDATE_BYTE_OFFSET` which tells that do not update the current file position after reading a file (which generally happens).

If this flag is set, the `offset` parameter suggests to read from specified position by `offset` in the file.

So in your case, you have specified `offset=0` and `length=1024`, it is correctly reading - `1 to 1024` - 1KB bytes from file. If you do same call again without changing `offset` parameter it will read same 1KB bytes.

Documentation from [FltReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/ff544286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) look at *ByteOffset* parameter documentation.

> ByteOffset [in, optional] Pointer to a caller-allocated variable that
> specifies the starting byte offset within the file where the read
> operation is to begin.
>
> If this offset is supplied, or if the FLTFL_IO_OPERATION_DO_NOT_UPDATE_BYTE_OFFSET flag is specified in the
> Flags parameter, FltReadFile does not update the file object's
> CurrentByteOffset field.